# Problems executing make USE_PGXS=1 on Ubuntu 14.04(postgresql9.3)

Tags: 14.04, postgresql

Following guide for Postgresql9.3 on ubuntu I am getting an error executing

```
make USE_PGXS=1
```

The output is:

```
gcc -g -O2 -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -Wformat -Werror=format-
security -I/usr/include/mit-krb5 -fPIC -pie -DLINUX_OOM_SCORE_ADJ=0 -fno-omit-
frame-pointer -Wall -Wmissing-prototypes -Wpointer-arith -Wdeclaration-after-
statement -Wendif-labels -Wmissing-format-attribute -Wformat-security -fno-strict-
aliasing -fwrapv -fexcess-precision=standard -g -fpic -I. -I./ -
I/usr/include/postgresql/9.3/server -I/usr/include/postgresql/internal -
D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -D_GNU_SOURCE -I/usr/include/libxml2  -I/usr/include/tcl8.6  -c 
-o src/tds_fdw.o src/tds_fdw.c
src/tds_fdw.c:52:22: fatal error: sybfront.h: No such file or directory
#include <sybfront.h>
                  ^
compilation terminated.
make: *** [src/tds_fdw.o] Error 1
```

How can i fix this? What is wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install [`freetds-dev`](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?searchon=contents&keywords=sybfront.h&mode=exactfilename&suite=trusty&arch=any):

```
sudo apt-get install freetds-dev
```